# "ImportError: libcupti.so.11.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" only with Poetry envs

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, python-venv, python-poetry

I'm working on a project that use sentence-transformers 2.2.2 and if I create the virtual environment with

```
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The application run without any problem.

I'm converting the project to Poetry but when I create the virtual environment using Poetry and the I run the application I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from app.src.common.utils import get_categories, get_models
  File "/home/mdonato/Documents-backup/jobs-data-analysis/app/src/common/utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
  File "/home/mdonato/Documents-backup/jobs-data-analysis/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datasets import SentencesDataset, ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "/home/mdonato/Documents-backup/jobs-data-analysis/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .DenoisingAutoEncoderDataset import DenoisingAutoEncoderDataset
  File "/home/mdonato/Documents-backup/jobs-data-analysis/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/DenoisingAutoEncoderDataset.py", line 1, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data import Dataset
  File "/home/mdonato/Documents-backup/jobs-data-analysis/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
    from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
ImportError: libcupti.so.11.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I followed [this](https://gist.github.com/denguir/b21aa66ae7fb1089655dd9de8351a202) guide for the instruction of the NVIDIA driver, CUDA and cuDNN.
I also followed the [Tar file installation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#installlinux-tar) so I tried to install in both ways but I'm still having the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar problem [here](https://github.com/sanchit-gandhi/whisper-jax/issues/108) that is solved fixing `torch<2.0.1`. The same solution works for me while building an inference docker image of the Nvidia [base image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nvidia/cuda/11.8.0-runtime-ubuntu22.04/images/sha256-0b654e1fcb503532817c27b4088d0f121b86eaeb7676b2268dd4e448df333bea?context=explore).

Your [package](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/requirements.txt) have no upper limit for torch version. You are probably installing `2.0.1` which also gave me the error you are seeing.